# Groups of order $p^2$ abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that $|Z(G)|= p \ or  \ p^2$ In the second case there's is nothing to do. And if $|Z(G)|=p$ then $G/Z(G)$is cyclic hence G abelian.

But my book has a different proof that I really want to understand.

Here it is:

If $|G|=p^2$ and $Z(G) \neq G$, then let $a \in G - Z (G)$. Then $C(a)$
is a subgroup containing both $a$ and $Z(G)$, with $| Z(G)| = p$. This shows that $C(a) = G$, a contradiction. Thus $Z(G) = G$, and so G is abelian.

I don't see why $Z(G) \subseteq C(a)$

and I guess $C(a) = G$ implies $a\in Z(G)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm assuming that $C(a)$ is the centralizer of the set $\{a\}$ i.e. the group consisting of all elements of $G$ commuting with $a$.  Since elements of $Z(G)$ commute with $\pmb{all}$ elements of $G$ they commute with $a$ in particular. Thus $Z(G)\subset C(a)$. Also you state $|Z(G)|> p$, in the fourth paragraph, but do you mean $|Z(G)| = p$?

Anyway, is it now clear how the result follows (given that the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group?

Comment: Thanks :D, your wording made it easier to understand.

Comment: Since $Z(G)=p$ and $a,Z(G)\subset C(a) \rightarrow C(a) \geq p+1$ but since $|G|$divides$ \ | \ C(a)|$, $|C(a)|=p^2$, So from the class equation $p^2=|G|\neq p +p^2 = |Z(G)|+ \sum_{\forall x\in G-Z(G)}[G:C(x)]$ Contradiction

Comment: Does it look good?

Comment: Looks good, but you could make this shorter. By Lagrange's theorem $|C(a)| | |G| = p^{2}$ so $|C(a)| = 1,p$ or $p^{2}$ ($p$ is prime so these are the only factors of $p^{2}$). Since $|Z(G)| = p$, $a\not\in Z(G)$ and $\{a\}, Z(G)\subset C(a)$ we must have $|C(a)| \geq p+1$. But then by the first line $|C(a)| = p^{2}$, thus $C(a) = G$ implying that $a$ commutes with everything in $G$, contradicting the assumption that $a\not\in Z(G)$